# Desafio C++, ajuda com a lógica

Tags: c++

Recebi uma lista de exercícios do professor de programação, este esta como desafio.

> escrever uma função com quer retorne o valor da expressão
>   `y = i - i^2 + i^3 -i^4 +i^5 - ... +- i^n`

Pensei em fazer *recursion*, mas não consegui desenvolver a lógica. Enfim, não tenho ideia nem de como começar. Se algum puder me dar alguma dica ficaria agradecido.

Comment: Por favor, quem está negativando, comente alguma coisa.

Comment: Explica um pouquinho melhor... a função deve receber um parâmetro `n` e ele deve ser o limite e um outro `i`? e então retornar `y`?

Comment: Acho que a razão que estão a negativar é porque é um desafio que lhe foi proposto, é o mesmo que alguem lhe fazer os tpc.

Mas agora o importante, devia explicar melhor a o valor de `i` e `n`

Comment: acredito que seja isso mesmo @krystalgamer, ele está "colando" em um teste, mas podemos ajudar mesmo sem dar a resposta... mas como vc mencionou... precisamos de mais infos...

Comment: Acho que `...` e `i^n` juntos significa que para qualquer `i` a expressão retorna um valor - mas na minha ignorância matemática isso está parecendo estouro de pilha... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Bem, temos três variáveis nesse contexto: `y` é o valor a ser descoberto, `i` provavelmente seja um valor informado para se fazer o cálculo e `n` seria a quantidade de vezes que o cálculo deve ser feito.
Analisando o problema:

```
y = i - i^2 + i^3 -i^4 +i^5 - ... +- i^n
```

Pude perceber um padrão. Inicialmente temos o valor de `i`, e logo em seguida uma subtração pela soma de `i` elevado ao sucessor de cada potencia `(i^2) + (i^3)`  e logo depois essa dupla é subtraída pela soma de outra dupla seguindo o mesmo padrão: `((i^2) + (i^3)) - ((i^4) + (i^5))`.

Caso eu tenha intendido corretamente, o seguinte código em **C#** teóricamente resolveria o problema:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Informe o valor de i: ");
        double i = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Informe o valor de n: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double y = i;

        for(int x = 2; x <= n; x++)
        {
            y = y - (Math.Pow(i,x) + Math.Pow(i,(x+1)));
            x++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("O valor de y = " + y);
```

Fiz o seguinte [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Ka70x) onde você pode fazer testes...
Como tarefa, basta tentar rodar em C++.

> Caso eu não tenha entendido direito, por favor, basta comentar antes
>   do -1.

Comment: Porque respondeu em c#??

Comment: @krystalgamer Meu palpite é que é a linguagem que ele tem mais familiaridade, e se você tem que que escolher uma pra escrever o exemplo, porque não usar a que você sabe mais?

Comment: @Gabe isso não faz sentido nenhum. Eu sei C e um pouco de C#. Isso não quer dizer que quando faço um pergunta em C me respondam em C#. Pergunto alhos e respondem bugalhos. Por alguma razão existem as `tags`

Comment: @krystalgamer Não discordo de você, mas numa pergunta aberta que pede exemplos de código, isso pode acontecer. Não é totalmente incomum que perguntas que envolvam a criação ou revisão de algorítimos acabem tendo respostas que indicam o algoritmo correto mas sem escrevê-lo na linguagem que foi pedida. Se ajudam ou não é algo que o AP deve decidir - talvez até editando a resposta com a linguagem correta.

Comment: Bem @krystalgamer percebi que a pergunta que o zezinho fez faz parte de uma tarefa dada pelo professor de programação, como ele mesmo esclarece na pergunta. Acredito que o professor esteja tentando familiariza-lo com a linguagem, então, respondendo em outra linguagem, estou ajudando com a lógica, mas fazendo com que ele se esforce em aprender mais da sintaxe da linguagem proposta pelo professor.

Answer (score 3):

Eis a implementação do programa:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double serieDePotencias(double x, unsigned int n){
    double resultado=0;
    for (int i=1; i!=n+1; ++i){
        resultado+=pow(-1,i+1)*pow(x,i);
    }
    return resultado;
}

// Programa principal
int main(){ 
    double valor;
    int potencia;

    // Pede os valores
    cout << "Introduza o valor de x: ";
    cin >> valor;
    cout << "Introduza o valor de n: ";
    cin >> potencia;

    // Resultados
    cout << "Soma da serie: " << serieDePotencias(valor,potencia) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outra forma de resolver a questão seria usar a expressão da soma para uma progressão geométrica. Seria um exercício básico e interessante para o utilizador implementar.

Answer (score 2):

A função abaixo retorna o valor esperado:

```
double f(double i, int n)
{
    double result{ 0. };

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        result -= pow(-i, j);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Veja que o sinal de cada parcela da soma `y = i - i^2 + i^3 -i^4 +i^5 - ... +- i^n` é determinado da seguinte forma: se o expoente da operação de potência é ímpar, o sinal da parcela é positivo; do contrário, é negativo. Portanto, é possível reescrever a expressão assim: `y = -[(-i)^1] - [(-i)^2] - [(-i)^3] - [(-i)^4] - [(-i)^5] - ... - [(-i)^n]`.

E para utilizar a função `pow(...)`, inclua o arquivo de cabeçalho `<math.h>`.

(OBS.: Para simplificar a função, eu estou supondo que o parâmetro `n` é positivo, isto é, `n >= 1`)